# I have a JSP page in which I want to search some results

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a JSP page in which I want to search some results. I'm doing it with a AJAX call and getting the result as a table, and am appending that table to a `div` in my page.

I wanted to perform some action using jQuery on the appended table but am not able to perform any action.

Comment: If you could add the code you are having problems with, that helps a great deal.

Comment: what kind of action do you want to perform on that appended table?for example according to your code $('#tableElementId').click event wont work properly but .on('click',function(){}); will work there is some small difference

Comment: (Btw, please don't repeatedly paste a small question to get around the length/code restrictions. Questions really are better with a more detailed description, and subverting the rules risk question closure).

Comment: Thanks for editing #halfer.i was asking question for the first time.I was not able to understand how u want me to format the question.I was just trying multi paste it worked.

Comment: To notify someone, the syntax here is `@halfer`, not `#halfer` (I only chanced upon your reply). Don't forget to reply to the folks below to indicate if their help has been useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.on` selector for handling events. Like

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );

 $("table").on('event', 'selector', function(){
       // your code here
  });
```

Comment: I would ask you to get updated with the latest jquery  syntax. **As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.** REF:https://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

You are saying some action to be performed on that appended table so, i gave you small example code for it

Example code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//This is what you want.. dont use click use on('click') ..
    $("#para1").on('click',function(){
           alert("para1 is clicked");
    });
)};
```

Comment: For your clarification.Iam not using ajax to get values but using it for getiing a jsp page as a response which contains a table with some id,on that table am not able perform any action using ajax.

Comment: the action that i want to perform is like 

    $("#table").on('click',function(){
           alert("table is clicked");
    }); try this this doesn't work

Comment: @Uppala i added some changes please see that

Comment: There is no mistake in this code ... provide me jsfiddle let me see